# Rails mailer best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know how to improve below lines of code.
Normally, I use the .deliver method in the model. Like below.

```
UserMailer.resend_confirmation(self, raw).deliver!
```

but since if error occurs like, i need to avoid this by adding begin statement

```
begin
  UserMailer.resend_confirmation(self, raw).deliver!
rescue; end
```

The problem starts when I'm still in development mode and I need to debug something. I need to comment it out so that I can hit the exception so my code looks like below now.

```
if Rails.env.production?
  begin
    UserMailer.resend_confirmation(self, raw).deliver!
  rescue; end
else
  UserMailer.resend_confirmation(self, raw).deliver!
end
```

Above code looks messy. Any ideas on how to improve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to debug ActionMailer in development mode add this line in development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

or if you want further testing of mail deliveries on testing/development env, you can read more here.

[Mailer Testing Reference](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers)